# Как обратиться к элементу коллекции конкретным value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, коллекции

```
<div class="col">
 <div class="field undecided">
    <input id="opt" type="checkbox" value="no" />
    <label for="opt">no</label>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input id="opt1" type="checkbox" value="cat" />
    <label for="opt1">cat</label>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input id="opt2" type="checkbox" value="dog" />
    <label for="opt2">dog</label>
  </div>   
  <div class="field">
    <input id="opt3" type="checkbox" value="hamster" />
    <label for="opt3">hamster</label>
  </div>  
  <div class="field">
    <input id="opt4" type="checkbox" value="rat" />
    <label for="opt4">rat</label>
  </div> 
</div>  

$(':checkbox').click(function(){        
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            if ($(this)[0].defaultValue === 'no') {
                $(this).parents('.col').find('.field').addClass('disabled-answer');
                //$(this)[0].val('no').removeClass('disabled-answer');
        $('.undecided').removeClass('disabled-answer');
            }
        }       
        else {$(this).parents('.col').find('.field').removeClass('disabled-answer');}
});
```

При выборе значения "no" все опции, кроме самой "no" должны становиться неактивными. Была отключена при клике активность всех элементов, а затем "возвращена" для "no". Но обратиться к "no" получилось только присвоив дополнительный класс undecided. Обращение как элементу коллекции (например $(this)[0].val('no')) он распознает как все элементы коллекции. Хотелось бы узнать, как в таком случае правильно обращаться вторым способом.

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/sncwaL15/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если все верно понял тот вот решение Вашего вопроса.

Этап выполнения:

1. выбрать все чекбоксы которые входят **.col**
2. исключить текущий чекбокс
3. установить всем остальным елементам **disabled** если выбранный чекбокс равен значению **'no'** иначе убираем **disabled**

При выборе любого чекбокса мы выбираем коллекцию всех чекбоксов и исключаем текущи

```js
    $(':checkbox').click(function(){
           var n = $(this);   
           n.closest('.col').find(':checkbox').not(n).prop('disabled', n.is(':checked') && n.val() === 'no');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
 <div class="field undecided">
    <input id="opt" type="checkbox" value="no" />
    <label for="opt">no</label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <input id="opt1" type="checkbox" value="cat" />
    <label for="opt1">cat</label>
  </div>  

  <div class="field">
    <input id="opt2" type="checkbox" value="dog" />
    <label for="opt2">dog</label>
  </div>   

  <div class="field">
    <input id="opt3" type="checkbox" value="hamster" />
    <label for="opt3">hamster</label>
  </div>   

  <div class="field">
    <input id="opt4" type="checkbox" value="rat" />
    <label for="opt4">rat</label>
  </div> 

</div>
```